# Tenser's Circular Shield

Tags: dnd-4e, magic-items, rituals

Tenser's Circular Shield: The item says it's an optional focus for the Tenser's Floating Disk ritual. Does that mean one can perform the ritual free of component costs (10gp)?

Comment: It's so much easier to just play a Psion, if you want Tenser's Floating Disk for free. ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, that's correct. An article in Dragon #385, "Ritually Speaking: Item Focus Rituals," introduced the concept of item focus rituals. These allow specific magic items to serve as a focus for the ritual without the need for ritual components. It's a great way to encourage your players to use rituals and to make magic items seem more wondrous.

Comment: thank you vary much, I had another dm tell me that you still had to pay the ritual cost.